# Number of root clusters

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, roots

Is there any way to tell how many clusters there are with respect to all the roots of a polynomial?

Specifically, I'm after the multiplicity of each root but since I would like to work in floating-point arithmetic I'm afraid I have to deal with clusters.

I don't mind any method of finding out: be it by numerical-iterative means during the convergence, a priori/a posteriori guess, maybe some matrix method would help..? If I have to set some small disk radius, that's ok, too.

Comment: Just so I understand - By cluster you mean several roots of the polynomial that are very close to each other (or the same root repeated several times) right?

Comment: @OriaGruber Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably *the* single most important result you need to know is [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem).

However, for postprocessing the output of numerical iterative methods ([Aberth-Ehrlich, Durand-Kerner, ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375869/polynomial-gcd-in-the-presence-of-floating-point-errors/1376517#1376517)), have a look at Siegfried Rump's [Ten methods to bound multiple roots of polynomials](http://www.ti3.tu-harburg.de/paper/rump/Ru03c.pdf); in particular methods 4 and 5 by Neumaier (based on Gershgorin circles of the companion matrix in a suitable basis).